How to capture SparkSQLParser logs in listappender of log4j
I encountered a problem in capture log4j listappender... Where as consoleappender I was able to capture all the sqls from the spark client (using log4j configuration SparkSqlParser and  with out printing them in the spark driver)
Is it possible at all to capture like this ?? If you see the output at the end captured logs are always empty from list appeneder where as console appender I was able to print them. Any help is greatly appreciated
This is my log4j where i am trying to capture the logs to listappender as well as consoleappender
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and specify the ListAppender and ConsoleAppender
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, ListAppender, ConsoleAppender

# Configure the custom ListAppender
log4j.appender.ListAppender=ListAppender
log4j.appender.ListAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ListAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Configure the ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Set logger for Spark SQL Parser
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser=DEBUG, ListAppender
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution=DEBUG, ListAppender
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=OFF
log4j.logger.org.sparkproject.jetty=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=OFF
log4j.logger.io.netty=OFF


this is my lisappender class
  import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class ListAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
  // Store logged events
  private val logList: ListBuffer[LoggingEvent] = ListBuffer.empty

  override def append(event: LoggingEvent): Unit = {
    logList += event
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {
    // Optionally handle cleanup if needed
  }

  override def requiresLayout(): Boolean = false

  // Method to retrieve logged events
  def getLogList: List[LoggingEvent] = {
    val lst = logList.toList
    lst.foreach(event => println(event.getMessage))
    logList.toList
  }
}

This is my sample sparkjob
 import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger, PropertyConfigurator}

object SparkSQLLogCaptureExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("log4j.properties"))
    // Initialize Spark Session
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL Log Capture Example")
      .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", s"-Dlog4j.configuration=file:" +  getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("log4j.properties"))
      .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:" +  getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("log4j.properties"))
      .master("local[*]") // for testing locally
      .getOrCreate()

//    // Configure ListAppender to capture logs for SparkSQLParser
   val listAppender = new ListAppender()
//    val parserLogger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)
//    parserLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
//    listAppender.activateOptions()
//   parserLogger.addAppender(listAppender)
    val sqlParserLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser")
    sqlParserLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
    sqlParserLogger.addAppender(listAppender)
    sqlParserLogger.debug("this is test msg")
    sys.addShutdownHook {
      println("Captured Logs:")
      val entries = listAppender.getLogList
      entries.foreach(event => println(event.getMessage))
      listAppender.getLogList.foreach(x => println("from list appender" + x))
    }
    // Example log messages
//    parserLogger.debug("*****This is a debug message.")
//    parserLogger.info("***This is an info message.")

    // Retrieve and print captured log entries

//    // Create and add ListAppender instance
//    val listAppender = new ListAppender
//    parserLogger.addAppender(listAppender)

    // Sample DataFrame and SQL Query
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq((1, "Alice"), (2, "Bob"), (3, "Carol")).toDF("id", "name")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

    // Execute SQL to generate logs in SparkSQLParser
    val query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id < 3"
    spark.sql(query).show()

    // Allow some time for logs to be captured after SQL execution
    Thread.sleep(1000) // Optional: Adjust sleep time as necessary for log generation


    // Stop Spark session
    spark.stop()
  }
}

finally this is my output :
2024-10-29T22:59:43,843 [main] DEBUG org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser  - this is test msg
2024-10-29T22:59:52,116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.CatalystSqlParser  - Parsing command: spark_grouping_id
2024-10-29T22:59:54,087 [main] DEBUG org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser  - Parsing command: people
2024-10-29T22:59:55,265 [main] DEBUG org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser  - Parsing command: SELECT * FROM people WHERE id < 3
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|Alice|
|  2|  Bob|
+---+-----+

Captured Logs:


i am using spark 3.3.2 scala 2.12 as envt
